# SwiftLint force new line after function opening bracket

Tags: regex, swiftlint

I'm trying to write some regex in order to force a new line after function opening bracket.Currenly my regex is `\{[^\n\{\}]*\n\n` but it returns the opposite thing and ideas?

Comment: The pattern matches 2 newlines. https://regex101.com/r/zb1fdn/1 Can you add an example? What do you mean with `"the opposite"?

Comment: I want to detect if the user hasn't entered a new line after opening bracket of the function

Comment: Do you mean using a lookahead instead? `\{[^\n{}]*(?=\r?\n)` https://regex101.com/r/KiN7Jt/1